# How to remove extra symbols from CURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have simple CURL request to the socket, which returns process pid. The problem is that there is some extra chars/symbols witch are unseen. My code is:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ ) {
    $ch = curl_init($server);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '<ping></ping>');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);

    $output = array(
        'result' => curl_exec($ch),
        'info' => curl_getinfo($ch),
        'error' => curl_error($ch)
    );

    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($output['result']);
    var_dump(trim($output['result']));
    var_dump($pid);
    echo "----------------\n";

    if (trim($output['result']) == $pid)
        die('TRUE');

    sleep(2);
}


die('FALSE');
```

Output looks like:

> bool(false) 
>  string(0) ""  
>  string(5) 
>  "14262" 
>   ---------------- 
>  string(7) "14262" 
>  string(7) "14262" 
>  string(5) "14262" 
>   ---------------- 
>  string(7) "14262" 
>  string(7) "14262" 
>  string(5) "14262" 
>   ---------------- 
>  FALSE

Comment: this is not the output from exactly this script. also it is unclear where `$pid` is defined and how `$server` looks like

Answer (score 0):

Try to use.

```
if (strcmp(trim($output['result']), $pid) == 0)
    die('TRUE');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preg replace that replaces every other char than number and then cast to integer

```
$output['result']) = intval(trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $output['result']))));
```

`[^0-9]+` means anything but number